# Drop logs from promtail

Tags: grafana-loki, promtail

I have prometheus + loki + grafana + promtail setup.
I need to drop the logs which have the words `healthcheck` or `health-check`.

My values.yaml file: https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/promtail/values.yaml

Please help me how can I do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this at the filtering stage in the pipeline

```yaml
pipelineStages:
# - cri: {}
- drop:
    expression: "(.*/health-check.*)|(.*/health.*)"
```

[docs](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/promtail/stages/drop/)